# React Native APK crashes when clicking on MapView ( Using React Native Maps - React Native Expo ) Platform : Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, react-native-maps

Description:

I'm currently working on a React Native project that incorporates the React Native Maps library. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the APK crashes as soon as I click on the MapView component.

Code snippet:

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  HStack,
  Spinner,
  Heading,
  Select,
  Box,
  CheckIcon,
  Slider,
} from "native-base";
import youAreHere from "../../assets/youAreHere.png";
import getDirections from "react-native-google-maps-directions";
import { getDistance } from "../../utils";
import YouAreHere from "./YouAreHere";
// react-native-maps -> package to display the Map.
// expo-location -> get current location in terms of coordinates.
import MapView, { Marker, Polyline } from "react-native-maps";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

const Map = () => {
  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(null);
  const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = useState(null);
  const [allMarkers, setAllMarkers] = useState(null);
  const [activeGroup, setActiveGroup] = useState(null);
  const [distanceFilterValue, setDistanceFilterValue] = useState(10);
  const [navigationSource, setNavigationSoruce] = useState(null);
  const [navigationDestination, setNavigationDestination] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserLocation();
  }, []);

  const getUserLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
    } else {
      // console.log("Location Permission Granted!");
    }
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
    // Change this to the GPS Latitude and Longitude during production time.
    setCurrentLocation({
      latitude: 46.46753,
      longitude: 6.835,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://yucca-interface.vercel.app/swissmapcoordinates")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setGroupDetails(response.data.groupDetails);
        setAllMarkers(response.data.locations);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
  const navigate = () => {
    const data = {
      source: navigationSource,
      destination: navigationDestination,
      params: [
        {
          key: "travelmode",
          value: "driving", // may be "walking", "bicycling" or "transit" as well
        },
        {
          key: "dir_action",
          value: "navigate", // this instantly initializes navigation using the given travel mode
        },
      ],
    };
    if (navigationSource !== null && navigationDestination !== null) {
      getDirections(data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 rounded-lg bg-white">
      {allMarkers === null ? (
        <View className="flex items-center justify-center w-[100%] h-[100%]">
          <HStack space={2} className="flex items-center justify-center">
            <Spinner accessibilityLabel="Loading posts" size={30} />
            <Heading color="primary.500" fontSize="xl">
              Loading ...
            </Heading>
          </HStack>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View className="h-[10%] flex items-center justify-around flex-row">
            <TouchableOpacity
              className="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-2"
              onPress={() => {
                setActiveGroup(null);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>View All </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center space-x-3">
              <Box className="bg-blue-200 my-2 rounded-md">
                <Select
                  minWidth="100"
                  maxHeight="10"
                  placeholder="Start"
                  className="  text-center text-[15px] "
                  color="black"
                  _selectedItem={{
                    bg: "blue.100",
                    endIcon: <CheckIcon size="4" />,
                  }}
                  mt={1}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
                    console.log(itemValue);
                    setNavigationSoruce(itemValue);
                  }}
                >
                  {allMarkers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <Select.Item
                      key={index}
                      label={marker.name}
                      value={marker.coordinates}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </Box>
              <Box className="bg-blue-200 my-2 rounded-md">
                <Select
                  minWidth="100"
                  maxHeight="10"
                  placeholder="End"
                  className="  text-center text-[15px] "
                  color="black"
                  _selectedItem={{
                    bg: "blue.100",
                    endIcon: <CheckIcon size="4" />,
                  }}
                  mt={1}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
                    console.log(itemValue);
                    setNavigationDestination(itemValue);
                  }}
                >
                  {allMarkers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <Select.Item
                      key={index}
                      label={marker.name}
                      value={marker.coordinates}
                    />
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </Box>
              <TouchableOpacity
                className="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-2"
                onPress={() => {
                  navigate();
                }}
              >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>Navigate </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
              Locations within {distanceFilterValue} km
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Move The Slider</Text>
            <Slider
              defaultValue={distanceFilterValue}
              step={25}
              size="sm"
              width={100}
              Height="10"
              onChangeEnd={(finalValue) => {
                setDistanceFilterValue(finalValue / 10);
              }}
            >
              <Slider.Track>
                <Slider.FilledTrack />
              </Slider.Track>
              <Slider.Thumb />
            </Slider>
            <Box className="bg-blue-200 my-2 rounded-md">
              <Select
                selectedValue={activeGroup}
                minWidth="200"
                maxHeight="10"
                // accessibilityLabel={filterSetName}
                placeholder="Select Group"
                className="  text-center text-[15px] "
                color="black"
                _selectedItem={{
                  bg: "blue.100",
                  endIcon: <CheckIcon size="4" />,
                }}
                mt={1}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => {
                  console.log(itemValue);
                  setActiveGroup(itemValue);
                }}
              >
                {groupDetails?.map((groupDetail, index) => (
                  <Select.Item
                    key={index}
                    label={groupDetail.groupName}
                    value={groupDetail.groupCode}
                  />
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Box>
          </View>
          <MapView
            className="flex-1 rounded-lg"
            zoomEnabled={true}
            zoomTapEnabled={true}
            initialRegion={currentLocation}
          >
            {currentLocation !== null && (
              <Marker
                title="You Are Here"
                coordinate={currentLocation}
                onPress={() => {
                  console.log("You Are Here");
                }}
              >
                <YouAreHere />
              </Marker>
            )}
            {allMarkers
              .filter((marker) => {
                if (
                  activeGroup === null &&
                  currentLocation !== null &&
                  getDistance(
                    {
                      latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
                      longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
                    },
                    marker.coordinates
                  ) < distanceFilterValue
                ) {
                  return true;
                } else if (
                  marker.groupCode === activeGroup &&
                  currentLocation !== null &&
                  getDistance(
                    {
                      latitude: currentLocation.latitude,
                      longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
                    },
                    marker.coordinates
                  ) < distanceFilterValue
                ) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              })
              .map((marker, index) => (
                <Marker
                  key={index}
                  title={marker.name}
                  coordinate={marker.coordinates}
                  onPress={() => {
                    console.log(marker.name, marker.coordinates);
                  }}
                />
              ))}
            {navigationSource !== null &&
              navigationDestination !== null &&
              activeGroup === null && (
                <Polyline
                  coordinates={[navigationSource, navigationDestination]}
                  strokeColor="#1AA7EC" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
                  strokeWidth={6}
                />
              )}
          </MapView>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Expected behavior:

I expect the MapView component to function properly, allowing users to interact with the map without any crashes. However, clicking on the map currently triggers an immediate crash of the APK.

However code runs properly on Android Emulator using react Expo cli

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue with the MapView from react-native-maps too, but in my case the apk crashes inmediately every time it renders the map, so I can't even see the map. Maybe you have a similar issue.
Of all things I did, I think I solved the issue when I putted the next code inside the "android" options in the app.json file:

```
 "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "YOUR_API_KEY"
    }
  }
```

Source: [this github issue](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4769#issuecomment-1617761542).

I also tried a few more things like:

> Adding a "local.properties" file in the android folder with a **MAPS_API_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY**.

> Adding **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'** to build.gradle files in the android folder as a dependency.

> Adding the **<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /** tag within the application tag in the android manifest.

> Check if you have the **<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"** tag
> within the application tag in the android manifest.